If $P(x≤1)=1$, what's the value of $P(x<1)$
Motivation:- This came out of a printing mistake in the question paper of my sister(high school). But this genuinely made me overthink so much
Question

If $\log(x)≤0$ and $x^2+x-2≤0$, what is the probability that $x<1$

My futile attempt
This was corrected as a printing mistake, as it would be $x≤1$. In that case the answer is just $1$ because it's a sure event.
But if we try for $x<1$, with the domain including all real numbers,the probability of $x<1$ are almost $1$, but would it be $1$?

How is the probability measured here? $x$ is not a random variable.

This is impossible to answer without more context. Also, the tag (probability-limit-theorems) does not appear relevant.

It's not clear what distribution you have in mind, but if it is a continuous one, then $P(X=1)=0$, so there's no difference between $P(X<1)$ and $P(X≤1)$.

"The domain including all real numbers" is not enough information to state the probability of ANY event, unless it's impossible or certain.

I suggest:  write out the question exactly as it appears.  I think you must have left off a great deal of relevant context.  For instance, I expect you mean to be working with a conditional probability. That said, my earlier point stands.  If $X$ is drawn from a continuous distribution, then $P(X=1)=0$.

@sudeep5221 If you take the explicit wording of the posted question at face value, then you are asking an impossible question.  That is, the original poster has indicated that the math problem occurred to them, because of a printing mistake.  Therefore, it is reasonable to presume that the original poster has no other information to give.  Granted, this may make it impossible to provide a formal answer to the question.

@aschepler see my comment to sudeep5221.

@lulu see my comment to sudeep5221.

@user2661923 thank you so much for this.

@lulu but why is P(X=1)=0 for a continuous distribution? I'm just two years older to my sister and I'm in high school as well, and we don't have any of these terms in my probability chapter sadly. And Wikipedia explains it using more confusing terms. Is there a simple explanation to your claim and what's a continuous distribution?

@Gwen you can think of it this way. Consider the set $\mathcal{S} = {1/N, 2/N, \dots, N/N}$, where $N$ is some natural number. Let $X$ be a random variable that takes the values in the set $S$ with equal probability, i.e., $\Pr(X = 1/N) = \Pr(X = 2/N) = \dots = \Pr(X = N/N) = 1/N$. In other words, $\Pr(X = 1) = 1/N$. Now think of the scenario where $N$ goes to $\infty$, which is (somewhat) equivalent to considering the uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$. As $N \to \infty$, $\Pr(X = 1) \to 0$. Thus, if $X$ is a continuous distribution $\Pr(X = 1) = 0$.

The above comment is of course is no where rigorous but I hope that helps you build some intuition.

We have no idea what the distribution is!  You have given us no information at all about it.  I guessed it was continuous, but possibly I guessed wrong. No doubt the context of the problem provides more information.

@lulu Not necessarily.  From the constraints, you know that $~0 < x \leq 1.~$  So, absent the printing mistake, the high school question would be asking for the probability that $~x \leq 1.~$  So, the intended answer is $~1,~$ which represents certainty.  Given that prior to this problem, the original poster had not been introduced to the phrase uniform distribution, it seems very plausible to me that the problem provided no further information.

@user2661923 i don't think that makes sense.  Why would anyone ask "given that $x\leq 1$, what is the probability that $x \leq 1$?"  ?  I think there is missing context.

@lulu that's the thing. It was an MCQ question, you needed to derive that $x≤1$ is true for all values, thus making the probability 1. I have no other context sadly, that's the question

Well,  just trying us the $\log  x\leq 0$ suffices for that. The quadratic adds nothing.

@lulu Perhaps you are missing the point.  These are high school students, who perhaps just learned how to attack a quadratic inequality.  I surmise that the point of the question was to test the high school students' elementary understanding of logarithms, combined with their understanding of (for example) the completing the square approach to attacking a quadratic inequality.

$$\left( ~x + \frac{1}{2} ~\right)^2 + \left( ~ \frac{-1}{4} ~\right) - 2 \leq 0 \iff $$
$$\left( ~x + \frac{1}{2} ~\right)^2 \leq \frac{9}{4} \iff $$
$$\left| ~x + \frac{1}{2} ~\right| \leq \frac{3}{2}. \tag1 $$
Regardless of whether logarithms are taken in base $~10~$ or are natural logarithms, you have that
$$\log(x) \leq 0 \iff 0 < x \leq 1. \tag2 $$
So, applying the constraint in (2) above to the constraint in (1) above, you have that
$$0 < x ~~~~\text{and} ~~~~x + \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3}{2}.$$
Therefore, the complete set of all satisfying values of $~x~$ is in fact
$$0 < x \leq 1.$$
Denoting the set $~S~$ as $ ~\{ ~x ~: ~0 < x \leq 1 ~\},~$ if you take any random element $~s~$ from the set $~S,~$ the probability that $~s = 1~$ is $~0.~$
Consistent with the original poster's informal intuition, this can be shown as follows:
Choose any $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.~$
Partition $~S~$ into the mutually exclusive subsets $~S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n,~$ where
$$S_k = \left\{ ~x ~: ~\frac{k-1}{n} < x \leq \frac{k}{n} ~\right\} ~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$$
Then, the probability that a random element $~s~$ is in $~S_n = \dfrac{1}{n}.$
Edit
As pointed out in the comment by aschepler, immediately following this answer, I am assuming a uniform distribution of the element $~s~$ in $~S.$  Based on the posted question, I see nothing to contradict this assumption, which makes the analysis convenient.
However, I imagine that the probability that $~s = 1~$ will equal $~0,~$ in a variety of distributions, other than a uniform distribution.  So, a case can be made that my approach is (arguably) invalid.  Anyway...
Therefore, the probability that $~s = 1~$ is $~\leq \dfrac{1}{n}.$
This holds for any $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$
Now suppose that the probability that $~s = 1~$ equals $~\epsilon > 0.~$
Choose $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}~$ such that
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon} < n \implies \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon.$$
Then, you have that the probability that $~s = 1~$ is :

Equal to $~\epsilon.$

Less than or equal to $~\dfrac{1}{n},~$ which is less than $~\epsilon.$


This yields a contradiction.
Therefore, there can not exist any positive $~\epsilon,~$ such that the probability that $~s = 1~$ is $~\epsilon.$
Therefore, the probability that $~s = 1~$ must be equal to $~0.$

$~\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
A case can be made that my response constitutes beating a dead horse.  That is, I imagine that the same analysis has been presented, in similar circumstances, more than once on MathSE.
Despite that, I feel that a response must be shaped to accommodate the target audience.  In this particular instance, I think that directly re-presenting the analysis constitutes (by far) the most effective communication of the idea.

That $P(x \in S_n) = \frac 1 n$ assumes a uniform distribution.

@aschepler +1 : Very nice catch, which shows the gap in my knowledge of probability theory.  I have edited my response accordingly.

Can you please explain what's a uniform distribution in simple words? I'm in high school as well and our syllabus doesn't cover this :") and Wikipedia uses all fancy words

@Gwen Informally, as a simple example, it means that if $~C~$ is a constant such that $~0 < C < 1,~$ and a random number $~x~$ is selected such that $~0 < x \leq 1,~$ then the probability that $~x < C~$ is $~C.~$  So, the probability that a random value taken from $~(0,1]~$ is less than $~1/3~$ is $~1/3,~$ the probability that the random value is less than $~4/7~$ is $~4/7,~$ and so forth.

@Gwen Re my last comment, in high school, this is not something that you should be concerned about.  It is only if you take a college probability course, or self-study a college level probability book that you would expect the subject to then make sense.

I think I understood it. I was intuitionally thinking it to be like a limit as $x\to 1$ , $P\to 1$ , but what was bugging me is that whatever we do, a random choice for the event (x<1) can never include $1$, but for (x≤1) can, so I couldn't wrap my mind around how both are still having the same probability. Thanks to you for the answer, I think I understood now
